# need a query that finds total between two dates but that also updates over time

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a fiscal year of `07/01/2013 - 06/30/2014` and I need to find the total amount of $ raised between those times. However, I need this query to account for the future, e.g. the next fiscal year will be `07/01/2014 - 06/30/2015`, so I will need to display the total donation amount for that fiscal year (and every year after)

This is what I came up with, but it's not returning any total value when I run it:

```
(select ifnull(sum(amount),0) 
from tableName
where date >= adddate('2013-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1)  year)
and date >=  adddate('2014-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1)  year)
)
```

Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: create a calendar table that has the date as the primary key.  Store the relevent fiscal year in each record.  Then this query will be simple.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Can you share some sample data, the result this query produces and the result you expect?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just saw my error in the fifth line. It should be: (select ifnull(sum(amount),0) 
from tableName
where date >= adddate('2013-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1)  year)
and date **<** adddate('2014-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1)  year)
)

Comment: If you solved your own problem, you can either post it as the answer and/or put `[SOLVED]` in the title, or delete your question altogether.

Comment: now you just need to mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select ifnull(sum(amount),0) 
from tableName where date >= adddate('2013-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1) year) 
and date < adddate('2014-07-01', interval 
if(month(curdate()) > 6, year(curdate())-2013,year(curdate())-2013-1) year) 
)
```